# How can I deconvolve a spectrum to get the information about each of the deconvolved spectra?

Tags: signal-processing

I have a spectrum with two peaks. I want to deconvolve it by gaussian so that I get the parametres (e.g. peak position, area, FWHM, Height) of each deconvolved spectrum.
I have tried the following:

```
data={{400, 0.04}, {401, 0.039}, {402, 0.04}, {403, 0.039}, {404, 
  0.039}, {405, 0.039}, {406, 0.04}, {407, 0.04}, {408, 0.04}, {409, 
  0.04}, {410, 0.04}, {411, 0.04}, {412, 0.04}, {413, 0.041}, {414, 
  0.041}, {415, 0.042}, {416, 0.041}, {417, 0.041}, {418, 
  0.041}, {419, 0.042}, {420, 0.042}, {421, 0.042}, {422, 
  0.042}, {423, 0.042}, {424, 0.043}, {425, 0.043}, {426, 
  0.043}, {427, 0.044}, {428, 0.045}, {429, 0.046}, {430, 
  0.047}, {431, 0.048}, {432, 0.049}, {433, 0.049}, {434, 
  0.051}, {435, 0.052}, {436, 0.053}, {437, 0.055}, {438, 
  0.057}, {439, 0.059}, {440, 0.061}, {441, 0.063}, {442, 
  0.066}, {443, 0.068}, {444, 0.071}, {445, 0.074}, {446, 
  0.076}, {447, 0.08}, {448, 0.083}, {449, 0.088}, {450, 0.092}, {451,
   0.097}, {452, 0.101}, {453, 0.105}, {454, 0.11}, {455, 
  0.115}, {456, 0.12}, {457, 0.125}, {458, 0.131}, {459, 0.136}, {460,
   0.142}, {461, 0.148}, {462, 0.154}, {463, 0.161}, {464, 
  0.168}, {465, 0.175}, {466, 0.183}, {467, 0.192}, {468, 
  0.201}, {469, 0.211}, {470, 0.221}, {471, 0.233}, {472, 
  0.247}, {473, 0.26}, {474, 0.276}, {475, 0.294}, {476, 0.311}, {477,
   0.329}, {478, 0.349}, {479, 0.369}, {480, 0.391}, {481, 
  0.413}, {482, 0.437}, {483, 0.46}, {484, 0.484}, {485, 0.508}, {486,
   0.531}, {487, 0.554}, {488, 0.578}, {489, 0.6}, {490, 0.622}, {491,
   0.643}, {492, 0.663}, {493, 0.681}, {494, 0.699}, {495, 
  0.715}, {496, 0.731}, {497, 0.745}, {498, 0.759}, {499, 
  0.773}, {500, 0.786}, {501, 0.8}, {502, 0.815}, {503, 0.832}, {504, 
  0.85}, {505, 0.87}, {506, 0.894}, {507, 0.921}, {508, 0.95}, {509, 
  0.982}, {510, 1.019}, {511, 1.059}, {512, 1.102}, {513, 
  1.149}, {514, 1.199}, {515, 1.25}, {516, 1.302}, {517, 1.356}, {518,
   1.409}, {519, 1.461}, {520, 1.511}, {521, 1.557}, {522, 
  1.597}, {523, 1.63}, {524, 1.656}, {525, 1.674}, {526, 1.683}, {527,
   1.683}, {528, 1.672}, {529, 1.651}, {530, 1.62}, {531, 
  1.579}, {532, 1.528}, {533, 1.469}, {534, 1.403}, {535, 1.33}, {536,
   1.25}, {537, 1.165}, {538, 1.08}, {539, 0.996}, {540, 0.913}, {541,
   0.83}, {542, 0.752}, {543, 0.677}, {544, 0.606}, {545, 
  0.541}, {546, 0.481}, {547, 0.426}, {548, 0.375}, {549, 0.33}, {550,
   0.289}, {551, 0.252}, {552, 0.219}, {553, 0.19}, {554, 
  0.165}, {555, 0.143}, {556, 0.123}, {557, 0.107}, {558, 
  0.092}, {559, 0.078}, {560, 0.067}, {561, 0.058}, {562, 0.05}, {563,
   0.042}, {564, 0.036}, {565, 0.031}, {566, 0.026}, {567, 
  0.024}, {568, 0.02}, {569, 0.018}, {570, 0.015}, {571, 0.012}, {572,
   0.011}, {573, 0.01}, {574, 0.008}, {575, 0.007}, {576, 
  0.006}, {577, 0.005}, {578, 0.004}, {579, 0.003}, {580, 
  0.003}, {581, 0.003}, {582, 0.002}, {583, 0.001}, {584, 
  0.001}, {585, 0.001}, {586, 0.001}, {587, 0}, {588, 
  0}, {589, -0.001}, {590, -0.001}, {591, -0.001}, {592, -0.001}, 
{593, -0.001}, {594, -0.001}, {595, -0.002}, {596, -0.002}, {597, 
-0.002}, {598, -0.002}, {599, -0.002}, {600, -0.002}, {601, -0.002}, 
{602, -0.002}, {603, -0.003}, {604, -0.003}, {605, -0.003}, {606, 
-0.003}, {607, -0.003}, {608, -0.003}, {609, -0.003}, {610, -0.003}, 
{611, -0.003}, {612, -0.003}, {613, -0.003}, {614, -0.003}, {615, 
-0.003}, {616, -0.002}, {617, -0.003}, {618, -0.003}, {619, -0.003}, 
{620, -0.003}, {621, -0.003}, {622, -0.003}, {623, -0.003}, {624, 
-0.003}, {625, -0.003}, {626, -0.003}, {627, -0.003}, {628, -0.003}, 
{629, -0.003}, {630, -0.003}, {631, -0.003}, {632, -0.003}, {633, 
-0.003}, {634, -0.003}, {635, -0.003}, {636, -0.003}, {637, -0.003}, 
{638, -0.003}, {639, -0.003}, {640, -0.003}, {641, -0.003}, {642, 
-0.003}, {643, -0.003}, {644, -0.003}, {645, -0.003}, {646, -0.003}, 
{647, -0.003}, {648, -0.003}, {649, -0.003}, {650, -0.003}}

fit = 

    NonlinearModelFit[
      data, 
      y0 + A1/(w1*\[Sqrt](2 \[Pi]))*Exp[-1/2*((t - xc1)/w1)^2] + 
       A2/(w2*\[Sqrt](2 \[Pi]))*Exp[-1/2*((t - xc2)/w2)^2], {{y0, 
        0.1}, {w1, 50}, {xc1, 493}, {w2, 20}, {xc2, 526}, {A1, 30}, {A2, 
        48}}, t]

    fitvalue = fit["BestFitParameters"]
    y0 = y0 /. fit["BestFitParameters"][[1]];
    xc1 = xc1 /. fit["BestFitParameters"][[3]];
    w1 = w1 /. fit["BestFitParameters"][[2]];
    xc2 = xc2 /. fit["BestFitParameters"][[5]];
    w2 = w2 /. fit["BestFitParameters"][[4]];
    A1 = A1 /. fit["BestFitParameters"][[6]];
    A2 = A2 /. fit["BestFitParameters"][[7]];
    
    peak1 = N[
       Table[{t, 
         y0 + A1/(w1*\[Sqrt](2 \[Pi]))*Exp[-1/2*((t - xc1)/w1)^2]}, {t, 
         400,650,1}]];
    peak2 = N[
       Table[{t, 
         y0 + A2/(w2*\[Sqrt](2 \[Pi]))*Exp[-1/2*((t - xc2)/w2)^2]}, {t, 
         400,650, 1}]];
    sumpeak = 
      N[Table[{t, fit[t]}, {t, 400,650, 1}]];
    Show[ListPlot[data, 
      PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thin}], 
     ListLinePlot[sumpeak, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}], 
     ListLinePlot[peak1, PlotStyle -> {Green, Thin}, 
      PlotRange -> {{400, 650}, {0, 2}}], 
     ListLinePlot[peak2, PlotStyle -> {Green, Thin}], 
     PlotRange -> {{400, 650}, {0, 2}}]
```

(where A1 and A2 are the area of the deconvoluted spectra an w1, w2 are the FWHM and xc1, xc2 are the peak positions of corresponding spectra)
Now, sometime it works, but not always. When the guess value are very close to actual fitted one, then it works, otherwise it does not.
So, how can I modify this or how to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Try `FindPeaks` to get a better initial guess for the main peak position. `peak = SortBy[FindPeaks[Last[Transpose[data]]],Last] // Last // First // Floor ;
peak = data[[peak]] // First`

Comment: Fitting 7 parameters is not easy. Therefore, the first I would do is to subtract a base line from 0.01 at the left end to 0.003 at the right end. Then you do not need the parameter y0. Next you need to guess good starting values. Looking at the derivative of the data may help for an educated guess:intp=Interpolation[data]; intp'[x] is the first derivative. Further, restarting the Fit with starting values for the peak positions from  the fitted position and repeating until it is self consistent. All this depends vey much from the variability of your data. You have to play with it.